# UI-Grid Remove $TreeLevel and Instrument ColumnDef's from Column Menu List

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have set the **$$TreeLevel** and **Instrument** ColumnDef's visbile property to false and I'd like for that to be permanent by removing those columDef names from the Column Menu so the user can't toggle it visible.

I see an enableHiding option I can set to false if the column is visible, which removes that column from the Column Menu, therefore disabling the ability to hide the column

I need that opposite functionality. So when a columnDef's visibility is false, those columns should be removed from the Column Menu list so they can't be seen.

I have set this property for the $$TreeLevel and Instrument ColumnDef's :

```
   `columnDef.visible = false;`
```

I haven't been able to find anything in the docs that would allow this. How can I remove those column names from the Column Menu so the user can't see them and make them visible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create fiddle or something with your code so people get better idea what you need.

Comment: Hi pegla, all I am really trying to do is remove the $$TreeLevel and Instrument columns from the Column Menu. So that when a user clicks on that hamburger menu those options are not listed there. Do you know if there is a property or anything that does that?

Comment: Is there only an enableHiding option and no enableShowing??